# If $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$, then is $H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(A,A)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$, then is $H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(A,A)$? I know this is true for usual homology grouups but does it also hold for relative homology groups?

On first sight, the proof that works for usual homology seems to generalise. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r:X\to A$ be a retraction i.e. $r\circ i=\text{id}_A$ such that $i\circ r\simeq \text{id}_X$, where $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion. Note that we can think $r:(X,A)\to (A,A)$ and $i:(A,A)\to (X,A)$. Now, use homotopy invariance of homology.

Comment: And I shouldl also use functoriality I guess to deduce that $i_*$ and $r_*$ are inverses of each other, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks! It was clear!